# Is there an efficient way to write if x of these variables are true in Python?

Tags: python, module, conditional-statements

I am writing a program where i need to check if 2 of these 4 booleans are true. Obviously i can write out every combination in an if statement, which is easy enough for 4 (alltho a pain). However, if the problem has 100 variables, and needs to know if at least 2 are true, now we have a much bigger problem. Is there a simpler solution to this? Is there a module that can do this for me? What if i want at least x to be true?

Comment: Add them up and check if the sum is 2. In the case of 100 booleans (I hope you store them in a list of dict), add them up and check if the sum is at least 2.

Comment: Can you post an example of this? Obviously you don't need 100 variables.

Comment: One easy answer is to use numpy. Check out this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html     Load your bools into a numpy array 'mybools', then test np.where(mybools == True), the returning array has the index positions of the bools that are true. Easy to check how many are true by checking length.

Answer (score 3):

You can take the sum of a list of bools. E.g.

```
a = True
b = True
c = False
d = False
e = True
f = False
g = False

bools = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]

print(sum(bools))
```

Outputs `3`.

Then compare this to whatever number you want, e.g. `sum(bools) >= 2`.

Answer (score 0):

assume the boolean array is `data`, then the following counts the number of True values

```
sum(data)
```

You can compare the returned value with `x`

Comment: `sum(data)` is all you need.